# How to help a mouse with an eye infection?

Tags: scratching, mice

We have a pet mouse who has some condition with her eyes that causes her to scratch them a lot. The local vet hasn't been particularly helpful (not for a lack of trying) and the various things they have offered us haven't helped much.

Her face is quite swolen up and she continues to scratch and causes her face to bleed. Other than the scratching she seems to be ok. My wife has been washing her face with cotton wool swabs and saline solution and it seems to help a bit but she still scratches a lot.

Does anyone have any ideas that might help?

Answer (score 2):

It's a possible allergy sign, have you tried changing food? Not sure what you're feeding her now, but you could try cutting out different food items to see if you can spot the source and/or put her on a rice-based diet.

Another possibility there is the bedding, also something to consider changing up. If you're using wood, consider dropping it for something dust free.

In any event, we tend not to think about allergies in animals, but they get them. I have a cat on a special diet because she has wicked food allergies and so most common cat foods send her into a scratching fit to the point of injury. Mice are no different in this respect.